# Launch Activity while parent is in the Background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-customtabs

I have an Activity `A` which starts doing some processing in its view model, meanwhile it launches a `CustomTab` which puts `A` in the background, when the viewmodel finishes its processing it requires to prompt the user to Activity `B` on top of the current one so I am aiming for a backstack like

`A` -> `CustomTab` -> `B`

However when I launch `B` from `A` the CustomTab activity stays on top until I close it manually, I am not sure if I am ending with a stack like this:

`A` -> `B` -> `CustomTab`

Or if B is not launched because `A` is not on the foreground.

Is there any way to move `B` on top? I have checked other questions that suggest using `SINGLE_TOP` and `CLEAR_TOP` on A but that will finish both `A` and `CustomTab` and I need them to stay alive so when `B` finishes it comes back to the browser.

Comment: What about this flag: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`?

Comment: Same result @Darkman